# Check pointer if it's array or not?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

how can i know to pointer is array or not?
Example:

```
    int main()
{
    int *a=new int [3] { 1,2,3 };
    std::cout << *a;
}
```

We have a "a" pointer, how to check its keep it self a array or single variable?

Comment: You can't. Why would you need to do that anyway?

Comment: @George i am trying to write smart_pointer manually, and i have to check if its a array, then i have to delete this like a array, i mean delete[]

Comment: @mstfyvtrl Research how `std::unique_ptr` does it. it's probably how you'll end up doing it as well. (distinction between `T` and `T[]` as the template type).

Comment: @mstfyvtrl There's a reason the standard smart pointers require you to tell them if they're pointing to the first element of an array.

Answer (score 2):

> how can i know to pointer is array or not?

You cannot find that out just based on the pointer value (nor the type).

You must know whether it is or isn't. If you don't know then to find out, you must look at where you got the pointer from.

Answer (score -3):

Using pointers arithmetic you could determine whether an **initialized** pointer is referring to an array or a single variable, for example coding something just like this would help you, adding that "1", you would be pointing the compiller out to access to the next position where is located the memory adress of the variable 'a', if it points to NULL, well no memory has been allocated in the adjacent position of 'a', so typically it'd be a pointer to a single variable.

```
int *a = new int [3] {1,2,3};
if (*(a+1)==NULL)
    cout<<"single variable";
else
    cout<<"array";
```

Comment: If pointer is to a single variable, then the behaviour of `*(a+1)` is undefined. Besides, you're comparing an integer to `NULL`.